# A que se debe el error TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy recién aprendiendo a usar python y estuve siguiendo un tutorial sobre PPO en python para entenderlo así mejor... No sé a que se deba el error, por que al parecer en el vídeo todo funcionaba correctamente.

```
class vehiculos():
def __init__(self,marca,modelo):
    self.marca = marca
    self.modelo = modelo
    self.frenar = False
    self.acelerar = False
    self.enmarcha = False

def arracar(self):
    self.arrancar = True
def frenar(self):
    self.frenar = True
def acelerar(self):
    self.acelerar = True
def estado(self):
    print("Marca: ", self.marca, "\nModelo: ", self.modelo, "\nFrenar: ", self.frenar, "\nAcelerar: ",
          self.acelerar,
          "\nEn marcha: ", self.enmarcha)

mifurgoneta = vehiculos("kia","cabc")
mifurgoneta.acelerar()
mifurgoneta.estado()


  File "/home/paxopaxo/PycharmProjects/untitled2/herencia 2.py", line 38, in <module>
  TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu problemas es que `self.acelerar` es un `booleano` definido al principio y no puedes llamar a un `metodo` igual que un `propiedad`

intenta asi:

```
class vehiculos():
    def __init__(self,marca,modelo):
        self.marca = marca
        self.modelo = modelo
        self.frenar = False
        # cambie acelerar por acelero
        self.acelero = False
        self.enmarcha = False

    def arracar(self):
        self.arrancar = True
    def frenar(self):
        self.frenar = True
    def acelerar(self):
        self.acelero = True
    def estado(self):
        print("Marca: ", self.marca, "\nModelo: ", self.modelo, "\nFrenar: ", self.frenar, "\nAcelerar: ",
              self.acelero,
              "\nEn marcha: ", self.enmarcha)

mifurgoneta = vehiculos("kia","cabc")
mifurgoneta.acelerar()
mifurgoneta.estado()
```